# React-typescript: how to enforce generic parameter and while also keeping keyof T

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Behold, a react-typescript component:

```
interface ComponentProps<A> {
  actions: A;
  onAction(key: keyof A): void;
}

function Component<A>(props: ComponentProps<A>) {
  return <div>{/* ... */}</div>;
}

<Component
  actions={{ a: 'one', b: 'two' }}
  onAction={action => {
    action; // type is "a" | "b"
  }}
/>;
```

I want to enforce: `A extends {[key: string]: string}` but I don't want to change the type of `action` to `string`. I still want that to be `"a" | "b"`

How do I do that? When I add `A extends {[key: string]: string}` it changes the type of `action` (from the usage in `onAction`) to a `string`.

Any ideas why?

Comment: Heh, the code you put up is working for me, the type of action is still `"a" | "b"` even with the extends. Maybe upgrade ts version?

Comment: @AlexGuerra i just updated to 2.7.2 (I was on 2.7.1) and now when i hover over the type, it says `keyof A` which i think is still correct because when I do `action === 'c'`. it correctly throws and error so I'll give ya the ✅ if you post that as an answer.